# Cannot use import statement outside a module (Bazel + Concatjs + NgRx)

Tags: angular, ngrx, bazel, bazel-rules-nodejs

#### The Issue

I am using [Bazel](https://bazel.build/) to build my Angular application.

Everything works fine with [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/) version 9.

But after upgrading NgRx to v10 or greater, the Angular development server breaks with this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at ts_scripts.js?v=32020367:12007
```

#### Minimal [Repro](https://github.com/flolu/bazel-concatjs-ngrx-issue)duction

To reproduce this issue follow these steps:

1. `git clone https://github.com/flolu/bazel-concatjs-ngrx-issue`
2. `cd bazel-concatjs-ngrx-issue`
3. `yarn install`
4. `yarn start` (Open http://localhost:4200, works fine)
5. `yarn upgrade-ngrx` (Upgrade NgRx to v11)
6. `yarn start` (Open http://localhost:4200, error in the browser console)

Note, that the production server `yarn prod` works fine on both versions of NgRx.

Therefore, this is a problem with the development server (in this case: [@bazel/concatjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bazel/concatjs))

Comment: The problem is that concatjs takes store_module.ngfactory.js (and other dependencies as well) and stuffs it into a an eval(). In eval, the static import statement is illegal and throws SyntaxError. Putting `type=module` on the ts_script `<script>` doesn't help with eval. The question is, why is `store_module.ngfactory.js` from `/esm2015` included in the final bundle. I tried to set target to es5 in tsconfig and that had no effect. Also, we are using the same ngrx store in our project and that factory file is not included in final bundles (we don't use Bazel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by the `ngfactory.js` files included with NgRx, however I'm unclear if these files should be part of the library distribution or not. It seems perhaps in older versions of Angular they were?

In rules_nodejs, the BUILD file generation for node_modules includes these `ngfactory` files in the `srcs` attribute of the generated `js_library`. (I *think* that's incorrect now, so we can fix that), these sources include `import` statements which aren't allowed outside of the modules (as the error states) as we are loading UMD.

A workaround around here is to either:

- [Patch rules_nodejs](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/blob/c47b770a122e9614516df2e3fdca6fe0bf6e3420/internal/npm_install/generate_build_file.ts#L941) to not add those files to the generated `js_library`
- Add a postinstall script to remove the `ngfactory.js` files from NgRx which runs before BUILD file generation. Example below:

`//:package.json`

```
diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
index 137c115..b322b55 100644
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -7,7 +7,7 @@
     "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.2.4",
     "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.2.4",
     "@angular/router": "^11.2.4",
-    "@ngrx/store": "9.1.2",
+    "@ngrx/store": "^11.0.1",
     "core-js": "2.6.9",
     "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
     "systemjs": "6.1.2",
@@ -29,7 +29,7 @@
     "@bazel/rollup": "^3.2.0",
     "@bazel/terser": "^3.2.0",
     "@bazel/typescript": "^3.2.0",
-    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "9.1.2",
+    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^11.0.1",
     "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.2",
     "@types/node": "^14.11.2",
     "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.15.0",
@@ -53,6 +53,7 @@
     "rollup": "^2.28.2",
     "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.1.0",
     "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
+    "shelljs": "^0.8.4",
     "terser": "^5.3.4",
     "typescript": "^4.2.3"
   },
@@ -60,7 +61,7 @@
     "start": "ibazel run //services/client:dev_server",
     "prod": "bazelisk run //services/client:app_server",
     "upgrade-ngrx": "yarn add @ngrx/store -D @ngrx/store-devtools",
-    "postinstall": "patch-package && ngcc"
+    "postinstall": "node postinstall.js && patch-package && ngcc"
```

`postinstall.js`

```
require('shelljs').rm(['node_modules/@ngrx/**/*.ngfactory.js', 'node_modules/@ngrx/**/*.ngsummary.json']);
```

To have this run after via after the yarn install via bazel:

`//:BUILD.bazel`

```
diff --git a/BUILD.bazel b/BUILD.bazel
index b91e927..d7a8767 100644
--- a/BUILD.bazel
+++ b/BUILD.bazel
@@ -2,6 +2,8 @@ load("@npm//@bazel/typescript:index.bzl", "ts_config")

 package(default_visibility = ["//:__subpackages__"])

+exports_files(["postinstall.js"])
+
 ts_config(
     name = "tsconfig",
     src = "tsconfig.json",
```

`//:WORKSPACE`

```
diff --git a/WORKSPACE b/WORKSPACE
index 7fabecb..cd0e095 100644
--- a/WORKSPACE
+++ b/WORKSPACE
@@ -18,6 +18,9 @@ yarn_install(
     package_json = "//:package.json",
     quiet = False,
     yarn_lock = "//:yarn.lock",
+    data = [
+        "//:postinstall.js",
+    ],
 )

 load("@io_bazel_rules_sass//sass:sass_repositories.bzl", "sass_repositories")
```

Applying this to your repro produces the "Hello world" as expected with the updated NgRx deps.